# How to read a specific slice of a (serialized) array from a file on disk into memory in Java?

Tags: java, file, serialization

I have a list of serializable objects that I want to store in a file in a master node. Files are the only thing I can use to store the data. There are multiple slave nodes, with direct access to the file, that want to read only a slice of the list and then process the data. Objects in the collection are serializable, but it is not mandatory that they are serialized.

Master Node

```
Collection<SerializableObject> l = getSerializableCollection();
writeDataToFile(l)
```

Slave Nodes

```
int id = getSlaveNodeID();
int leftIndex, rightIndex = getSliceOfArrayForSlaveNode(id)
Collection<SerializableObjects> l = readSliceOfArrayFromFile(leftIndex, rightIndex);
performComputationOnArraySlice(l);
```

How (if possible) can I read only a slice of that array in memory? I do not want to read the entire array in memory in every slave node because of the large file size and because a slave node must process only the slice from leftIndex to rightIndex in the array.

Comment: What you should do is create an "index file", which specifies where each node starts. That way, you can scan for the "index" of the data you want via in index file (if node 12,234 it would appear in index 12233). The index will tell you were to start reading from the main data file. You can also use [`RandomAcessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to seek to exactly where you want to start reading; an "index file" will help you determine *where* to start reading, based on the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i can give you a tip but cannot provide a working solution.

- Firstly, you should think about using a **custom output format** rather than serialisation.
  It works well when you have a state or not so many data to store, but **if you
  are working on large data-set i strongly encourage you to write your own**
  file format.
- Secondly, using your file format allows you to **define a custom reading function** *where you process line by line of your saves and keep in memory only a tiny fraction of the entire data-set.* `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` can help you to accomplish this task.
- In the end, *it may require a bit of effort* but **you will be able to parse only the data you need or all the data but using a tiny fraction of the memory.**

I hope this may help you